# POP3 mail box Send/Receive log

Tags: pop3

I want to write a code for some application in order to connect to a POP3 mailbox
and log the send and recieve transactions done on the mailbox even by other users,
or even read the built in log file if there is?
and Then send some notifications in some way to An admin Account
i dont know how to perform the action to write some (administration-Like) application to
do this on the given POP3 mailbox, I have read some articles on MSExchange but ...

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

All of the things you're talking about are administrative functions of the mail server, not features of the pop3 protocol itself.

As such, there's no way to answer this in the abstract (without knowing what kind of mail server is involved) - there's one answer for MS Exchange 2007, another for Dovecot, etc.

A good place to start is probably the administrator's documentation for your particular mail server.

Comment: you're right but the point is that i have to work on a pop3 mailbox,i mean the base form of my mail box must be pop3 form,by the way,if in my case MS Exchange is involved what is the answer?
how should it be done?

Comment: POP3 is a standard protocol for a mail client to pick up (read) mail from a server, nothing more. It's not a format for storing the mailbox on the server; different mail servers can use completely different means of storing mail (mbox format, maildir format, a database like Exchange uses, ...) and still present a POP3 interface.

Here's a link describing some of the log files that Exchange maintains on the server

http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2007/11/exchange-server-2007-how-many-logs-hath.html